# What single noun denotes a person who is interested in something?

Tags: single-word-requests

'Follower', 'disciple' and so on sound too strong. I want to describe a person with a more casual interest in something. Perhaps similar to what 'amateur' used to mean, before it picked up the sense of being crap at something. So say someone speaks fluent Chinese but they study Japanese on the side out of interest, I might say about them:

> They're a Chinese speaker, and Japanese [interested-in-er]

Comment: buff 2 (bŭf) n. *Informal* One who is enthusiastic and knowledgeable about a subject: *a Civil War buff.* TFD: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buff

Comment: Also, perhaps, *enthusiast.*

Comment: I think "enthusiast" is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @kris You should make that an answer.  It always baffles me when people bury the best answer in a comment.

Comment: You can consider _hobbyist_ also. (However, not a good fit for your example sentence because it can be understood that the hobbyist is Japanese. You can rephrase.)

Comment: _Novice_ has much the same meaning as _amateur_, without the negative connotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[enthusiast](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enthusiast) (ODO)

> *noun*
>   **1** A person who is very interested in a particular activity or subject:
>   *a sports car enthusiast*
>   *syn:* fan, … supporter, follower; … *informal* buff, …

Cited on TFD:

> He was as much of an enthusiast in art as I was, and not less anxious to learn to paint.
>   [*A Tramp Abroad*](http://twain.thefreelibrary.com/Tramp-Abroad/0-1#enthusiast) by Twain, Mark

Answer (score 0):

**Dilettante**

> dil·et·tante noun \ˈdi-lə-ˌtänt, -ˌtant; ˌdi-lə-ˈ\
>   : a person whose interest in an art or in an area of knowledge is not very deep or serious

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilettante

Unfortunately, once you get into these words such as amateur and layman that are less-serious, you do tend to have negative connotations. "Dabbles in..." is a construction I'm fond of, and I was planning to suggest "aficionado" but, as it turns out, that has a more serious denotation than I expected.