# Single word for one who enjoys something?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for one who enjoys something?

> I am not a movie critic but an '______' of  good movies.

Comment: [Enjoyer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enjoyer#other-words) is in Merriam-Webster so if you want to emphasise that you enjoy good movies, rather than appreciate them, are knowledgeable about them, advocate for them, are obsessed with them, devote all your time to them, etc, it may be the best word to use.

Comment: 'Fan' and synonyms are readily available.

Comment: Believe it or not, the best word I know for it is **Amateur** It is sadly not used that way though. One who does it "for love of it". The Royal Society in London was a place where these amateurs could meet. They created science as we know it. It is not used like that today, so to attract less downvotes, I leave it as a comment ;)

Comment: Fan, buff, afficionado, devotee, follower et al all work for me and isn't "I am not a movie critic but… " just confusing? Doesn't that set up an unreal opposition. By the same token, how would such a term be necessary? What would be wrong with "I enjoy (good) moviesbooks/food/anything"?

Comment: Best would be a phrase using the word to replace this curious use of "movie critic". 'I am not [any of the answers] but *I enjoy a good [noun] from time to time.*' - A single word for one who *overly* enjoys something.

Comment: How about a 'sucker'?

Comment: Your sentence isn't all that logical. The comparison is off. The *but* calls for something like a movie critic, but less so, or a non-professional movie critic. While movie critics might enjoy movies, that isn't their main job. *I'm an avocational movie critic.*

Comment: If you would like to avoid the more enthusiastic connotations of most of these answers, you might just say "but I like good movies."

Comment: A duplicate of [What single noun denotes a person who is interested in something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216667/what-single-noun-denotes-a-person-who-is-interested-in-something/216820#216820)

Answer (score 19):

If your enjoyment extends out to *enthusiasm*, the you would be an:

> [Enthusiast](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+enthusiast)
> noun
>
> 1. a person who is very interested in a particular activity or subject.
>    "a sports car enthusiast"

Answer (score 18):

[Fan](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fan)

> someone who admires and supports a person, sport, sports team, etc.:

Comment: Although the definition this answer provides may not seem to fit the OP's case, "fan" is actually used idiomatically to mean exactly what the OP is looking for. It's probably the most natural and most common word choice for exactly this.

Comment: _OED_ has this definition for the extended sense: "a keen follower of a specified hobby or amusement"

Answer (score 18):

A bit more high-brow: connoisseur.

[Source:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connoisseur)

> 1: Expert, especially: one who understands the details, technique, or
> principles of an art and is competent to act as a critical judge: "a connoisseur of music"

> 2: one who enjoys with discrimination and
> appreciation of subtleties: "a connoisseur of fine wines"

Comment: This was the first word that came to my mind as well.

Comment: When I looked it up, the definition I got was "an expert judge in matters of taste." That's a bit different from someone who likes something.

Comment: Added a quote from a dictionary to appease whoever voted to delete (!)...

Answer (score 17):

You could use *afficionado*, *devotee* and synonyms, but in the context of the question I would say

> I am not a movie critic but a movie **buff**.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/buff) has

> **buff ²**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A person who is enthusiastically interested in and very knowledgeable about a particular subject.

Comment: *Buff* seems stronger than what the OP has in mind. One can be interested in something and enjoy it, without being **enthusiastically** interested in it and **very** knowledgeable about it.

Comment: Thanks Lexico, but jsw29 is right,  I meant to imply a milder state of mind in my question.  I thought about fan, felt (perhaps wrongly) that it also suggests an enthusiasm or devotion that I did not want to convey.  Perhaps fan it is, though I hope the word has shed its reputation as being a shortened form of fanatic.

Comment: One possibility is *consumer.*

Comment: 'Buff' implies deep knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeking a word only in relation to movies, then *cinephile* would be the perfect term.  Your phrase would then be along the lines:

> I am not a movie critic but I'm certainly a cinephile.

The definition from [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A%20cinephile&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU794AU794&oq=define%3A%20cinephile&aqs) online is as follows.

> a person who is fond of the cinema.

However, if you are seeking a more generic word to describe someone who enjoys *something*, then you have a great many choices, some of which have already been offered by others (e.g. connoisseur, fan, etc).

Comment: *Cineast* also works for this usage.

Answer (score 2):

how about

fanatic
aficionado
cognoscente
admirer
devotee
addict

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

"Lover" - I am a lover of good movies.

"Lover" is defined as follows - a person who likes or enjoys a specified thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Enjoyer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enjoyer#other-words) is in Merriam-Webster so if you want to emphasise that you enjoy good movies, rather than appreciate them, are knowledgeable about them, advocate for them, are obsessed with them, devote all your time to them, etc, it may be the best word to use.

*<sub>-- [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579085/single-word-for-one-who-enjoys-something#comment1446198_579085) by [Stuart F](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/319429/stuart-f)</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

'a Cinephile' encapsulates "an 'enjoyer' of good movies."

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a word that can apply to many different things, not specifically films.

Comment: Cinephile only works for the specific example. I think the OP was after a more general term for someone who enjoys something.

Comment: True enough. Most things can take the suffix one way or another and it's a very common way of expressing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "-head" or "fiend" after mentioning the hobby if you want to talk about its fans

"He's a big metal-head", "I'm a book fiend"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more informal, and imply obsessive interest, you could consider "[fanboi](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fanboi)" or "fanboy".

> a male fan, especially one who is obsessive about comics, music, or
> science fiction

It has a somewhat negative connotation.